# Why does couchDB gives me not authorized error when trying to create views

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I am using couchDB and when ever i try to create views it is giving me this error

```
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  code: 'EUNAUTHORIZED',
  body: {
    error: 'unauthorized',
    reason: 'You are not a db or server admin.'
  }
}
```

I am using Node-Couchdb and i am passing the credentials like this

```
const NodeCouchDb = require('node-couchdb')
require("dotenv-flow").config();

const couch = new NodeCouchDb({
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    protocol: process.env.DB_PROTOCOL,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT
})

const couchAuth = new NodeCouchDb({
  auth: {
      user: process.env.DB_USER_NAME,
      pass: process.env.PASSWORD
  } 
})

module.exports = {
    couch
}
```

Comment: The *reason* is clear - how is your request composed? How are you authenticating (if at all?)

Comment: i am passing the credentials as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is creating **two** instances of NodeCouchDB, `couch` and `couchAuth` where

- `couch` points to server specified by envars *without* credentials
- `couchAuth` points to the default server (127.0.0.1:5984) *with* credentials specified by envars

You need to combine parameters, for example

```
const NodeCouchDb = require("node-couchdb");

const couch = new NodeCouchDb({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  protocol: process.env.DB_PROTOCOL,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.DB_USER_NAME,
    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
  },
});

module.exports = {
  couch
};
```